# Unable to scrape different owner names from different box-like containers out of a map

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, arcgis

I'm trying to click on a map using selenium so that I can scrape `parcel id` and `owner name` from box-like containers. When a click is made on that map, box-like container shows up. I would like to scrape `parcel id` and `owner name` from such container. This is how a [box-like container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6sRb.jpg) looks like. I tried using requests but could not find any way to locate the information available in such containers, so I'm trying now using selenium. The script below neither clicks on that map, nor throws any error.

[website with map](http://app01.cityofboston.gov/parcelviewer/)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "http://app01.cityofboston.gov/parcelviewer/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg#mapDiv_gc"))):
    item.click()
driver.quit()
```

How can I grab the parcel Ids and the owner names from different box-like containers out of that map?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why clicking randomly on the map ? is the goal to extract all box-like container information regardless of the position (location) ?

Comment: Right you are @Bertrand Martel. I would like to extract them all using requests or selenium. Btw, I've kicked out that word `randomly` from my post to avoid any confusion. Thanks.

Comment: please don't re-post questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62249688/6451573

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is data coming from ArcGIS REST Service.

I've located this Argis query call that returns the wanted data :

```
GET https://services.arcgis.com/sFnw0xNflSi8J0uh/arcgis/rest/services/Parcels19WMFull/FeatureServer/0/query
```

I've checked out what could be generating this url and found the following :

- http://app01.cityofboston.gov/parcelviewer/config/ParcelViewer.json returns a JSON object with a map ID `values.webmap` : `2da765769ee34446a396a9c9010f5631`
- this value is used to generate the following url : https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/2da765769ee34446a396a9c9010f5631/data which returns the query URL to find

This query call is called when you search for data in the input on the top left corner. You can edit the url parameters to match all data :

```
{
    "f": "json",
    "where": "1=1",
    "returnGeometry": "true",
    "spatialRel": "esriSpatialRelIntersects",
    "outFields": "*",
    "outSR": "102100"
}
```

It returns a maximum of 2000 items, so we'll need to iterate. To known how to iterate, we can checkout the content in the `features` array, checkout [this query](https://services.arcgis.com/sFnw0xNflSi8J0uh/arcgis/rest/services/Parcels19WMFull/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=false&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=FID%2CFULL_ADDRE%2CPID&outSR=102100)it gives something like that :

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "FID": 1,
    "FULL_ADDRE": "104 A 104 PUTNAM ST, 02128",
    "PID": "0100001000"
  }
},
{
  "attributes": {
    "FID": 2,
    "FULL_ADDRE": "18 LEVERETT AV #10-B, 02128",
    "PID": "0101399120"
  }
},
{
  "attributes": {
    "FID": 3,
    "FULL_ADDRE": "197 LEXINGTON ST, 02128",
    "PID": "0100002000"
  }
}
....
```

So we can iterate over the `FID` field using `where=FID > 2000` and for the next iteration we can just store the last FID we get and edit the where clause with `FID > {last_fid}`

So you can build a [python](/questions/tagged/python) script like this :

```
import requests

base_url = "http://app01.cityofboston.gov/parcelviewer"

# get map id
r = requests.get(f"{base_url}/config/ParcelViewer.json")
map_id = r.json()["values"]["webmap"]

# get the query url
r = requests.get(f"https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/{map_id}/data", params = {
    "f": "json"
})
url = r.json()["operationalLayers"][0]["url"]

params = {
    "f": "json",
    "where": "1=1",
    "returnGeometry": "true",
    "spatialRel": "esriSpatialRelIntersects",
    "outFields": "*",
    "outSR": "102100"
}

data = []
count = 1
finish = False

while finish == False:
    print(f"[{count}] requesting...")
    r = requests.get(f"{url}/query", params = params)
    entries = r.json()["features"]
    if len(entries) < 2000:
        finish = True
    else:
        last_fid = entries[-1]["attributes"]["FID"]
        print(f"next fid : {last_fid}")
        params["where"] = f"FID > {last_fid}"
    data.extend(entries)
    print(f"[{count}] received {len(entries)} items - total received : {len(data)}")
    count +=1

print(f"TOTAL: {len(data)}")

# print the last element (just to check)
print(data[-1])
```

After several minutes, the script has extracted 171922 records :

[image: record count]

---

This is what an entry looks like :

```
{
    'attributes': {
        'FID': 171922,
        'PID_LONG': '2205670000',
        'PID': '2205670000',
        'GIS_ID': '2205670000',
        'FULL_ADDRE': '2203 COMMONWEALTH AV, 02135',
        'OWNER': 'COMMWLTH OF MASS',
        'LAND_USE': 'E',
        'LAND_SF': 34125,
        'LIVING_ARE': 7386,
        'AV_LAND': 1325400,
        'AV_BLDG': 841100,
        'AV_TOTAL': 2166500,
        'GROSS_TAX': 0,
        'ID': 0,
        'SHAPE_Leng': 1003.12908156,
        'SHAPE_Area': 33512.6220608,
        'Shape__Area': 5702.6640625,
        'Shape__Length': 414.046143349521
    },
    'geometry': {
        'rings': [
            [
                [-7922244.91043368, 5212145.61745703],
                [-7922247.98527419, 5212105.5446644],
                [-7922243.75007186, 5212106.29247827],
                [-7922235.83595224, 5212062.80771992],
                [-7922239.05526106, 5212062.68000813],
                [-7922327.54387782, 5212214.66112252],
                [-7922281.74795739, 5212208.62518937],
                [-7922266.82960043, 5212207.97287607],
                [-7922241.02937963, 5212204.61661323],
                [-7922244.0269726, 5212158.45234151],
                [-7922244.91043368, 5212145.61745703]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

---

One last thing, just to check the result count directly on the API, we could use the query parameter from the Arcgis query UI like [this one](https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/0/query) (which is the map used in the website by the way). When filtered by count only, it adds the field `returnCountOnly=true`, lets do that in our query endpoint :

https://services.arcgis.com/sFnw0xNflSi8J0uh/arcgis/rest/services/Parcels19WMFull/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=false&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&outFields=FID%2CFULL_ADDRE%2CPID&outSR=102100&returnCountOnly=true

which returns correctly :

```
{"count":171922}
```

---

Note that you can apply some variant of this script for any Arcgis Rest service query type. I've made an example on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/b295f3805f087cda6bd4eefb1869caf0) to get the data from the map (cities). Note that the max result returned by the API may change depending on the service

Answer (score 1):

Try to solve it by click the element with specific `x y` position using the [**`.move_to_element_with_offset(to_element, xoffset, yoffset)`**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_to_element_with_offset) method in the `ActionChains` class. This will randomly click based on the `x y` specified in the list.

The starting point x is determined after the left navigation width, which is:

```
left_nav = driver.find_element_by_id('searchBox')
xstart = left_nav.size['width']
```

The starting point y is determined after the top navigation height, which is:

```
top_nav = driver.find_element_by_id('headerFrame')
ystart = top_nav.size['height']
```

The below code clicks with the constant y position:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#add following import
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

link = "http://app01.cityofboston.gov/parcelviewer/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
driver.maximize_window()
map_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg#mapDiv_gc')))

left_nav = driver.find_element_by_id('searchBox')
xstart = left_nav.size['width']

top_nav = driver.find_element_by_id('headerFrame')
ystart = top_nav.size['height']

#random x y here
xlist_increment = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900]
ylist_increment = [300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300]

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1)
action = ActionChains(driver)

for x, y in zip(xlist_increment, ylist_increment):
    xoffset = xstart + x
    yoffset = ystart + y
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(map_element, xoffset, yoffset)
    action.click()
    action.perform()

    try:
        parcel_id = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='esriPopupWrapper']//b[contains(text(), 'Parcel ID')]//parent::div")))
        owner_name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='esriPopupWrapper']//b[contains(text(), 'Owner')]//parent::div")))
        print(parcel_id.text)
        print(owner_name.text)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.close').click()
    except Exception:
        print("popup doesn't appear")

driver.quit()
```

Because clicking the `x y` position randomly, it does not guarantee that each click action can bring up the `parcel id` and `owner name` popup you mean, but I got it at least more than once.

**Output**:

> Parcel ID: 0302895000
>   Owner: SIXTY3-65 COURT ST LLC
>   Land Use: C

popup doesn't appear

> Parcel ID: 0302897000
>   Owner: SEARS CRESCENT BUILDING LLC
>   Land Use: C

popup doesn't appear

> Parcel ID: 0303694000
>   Owner: TWENTY-8 STATE STREET LLC
>   Land Use: C

popup doesn't appear

> Parcel ID: 0303685000
>   Owner: ANBECA 60 LLC
>   Land Use: C

popup doesn't appear

> Parcel ID: 0303746000
>   Owner: STATE ENTERPRISES LIMITED PA
>   Land Use: C

Comment: Your script grabbed info from a single container flawlessly but then stopped. I would like to get information from all the containers. However, it doesn't keep going. Thanks.

Comment: @MITHU I've updated the answer, hope this helps and give you a clue. At least better than my previous answer which only got 1 data result.